# How to build a downloaded a java source code in net-beans 6.9?

Tags: netbeans

I have downloaded source code from http://e-adventure.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/e-adventure/ . 
How do I build it and run it in netbeans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Compilation.txt file in the source code. You should read that and follow the directions. It says that it is an Eclipse project. Once you have followed the directions (notably downloading a jar file archive), you can try the:

```
File -> Import Project -> Eclipse Project
```

menu option and try and import it. Then, perhaps, it will build for you. I have not done this with an Eclipse project, so I don't know how well it works. It may well need some tweaking to get right.